# Setting view background with selector

Tags: android, selector

In my app I have ImageView that is added programmatically in onLayout method of its parent. I want it to have different background when it is focused different when pressed and different when on normal state. I defined some colors in values folder:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
   <color name="cream">#FBF9F5</color>
   <color name="green">#93D932</color>
   <color name="blue">#0095FF</color>
</resources>
```

Then I defined selector in drawables folder named table_background_selector.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
   <item android:state_selected="true" android:drawable="@color/green" />:
   <item android:state_pressed="true" android:drawable="@color/blue" />:
   <item android:drawable="@color/cream" />:
</selector>
```

Then i onLayout method of its parent after I initialized it I try to set background with:

```
v.setBackground(getContext().getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.table_background_selector));
```

And that's when IntelliJ shows me problem:

```
"Cannot resolve method 'setBackground(android.graphics.drawable.Drawable)'"
```

And I fail to understand why because View class has method 
setBackground(Drawable background)

Here is .png I set with setImageResource:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/s3rW5.jpg

[image]

Center of it is transparent and now it shows whatever background is set to app but I want it to display different colors when pressed or focused

I would be thankful for any help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check that you not importing the android `R` file by mistake instead of your local one, it certainly looks so.

**UPDATE:**

and for setting `ImageView` background do this:

```
image.setImageResource(R.drawable.your_drawable_resource);
```

Comment: But I want to set .png with some transparent sections as a resource and then change color of this sections with setBackground

Comment: you selector is responsible to change the button colors depending on the button state. so all you need to do is apply your background with the method I showed you.

Comment: I tried it but after that my ImageView shows only the background color and not the .png with transparent elements, I set before with setImageResource, on top of background

Comment: could you please show screen shot of what you are trying to achieve?

Comment: sadly I think that you can't apply background image and source image (in fact i think that background property is not applicable to ImageView) to imageView so you have to go another way, place you image inside of a FrameLayout and with it place a LinearLayout apply that background to the layout instead of the Image.

Answer (score 0):

first clean and builder you project still you getting same error then

Please check in import area whether you included this statement

import android.R;

if yes then you need to use your package name with include R like my.package.R.